# How to use the DataSource connection pool from server.xml within Hibernate Session?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the data sources configured in `server.xml`, and this datasource works  fine.

I need to feed these data sources to Hibernate Session

Here is that I tried

```
(DataSource) environmentContext.lookup(dataResourceName);
Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(connection); // does not compile 
try{
   Transaction tx = new Transaction();  
    /* something here */ 
   tx.commit();
}finally{
   session.close();
   conn.close();
}
```

However openSession method does not compile. Eclipse says this method should not have any arguments.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-connectionprovider-datasource

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't know why the above code doesn't even compile. This answer was accepted on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163157/can-use-hibernate-and-tomcat-connection-pool-at-same-time

Comment: Or maybe `openSession` method has arguments in earlier versions of hibernate

Comment: You'd better rely on the official user guide and documentation for your Hibernate version.